# What is the exact expected behavior of the `--quiet` CLI option?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

While adding some commonly supported options to a CLI tool, I ended up wondering: What behavior most people expect from the `--quiet` option?

More specifically, what about:

- Errors?
- User-valuable output? (e.g. `grep`ped content for `grep`)

As a more general sub-question:

- Is there any documentation or reference out there that indicates the general consensus regarding command line interface behavior for Linux(Debian) tools?

I would personally expect errors and user-valuable information to show up in some way (output, or exit code), but my only way right now is to test with common tools, and inspect how they behave. The tool I am working on mainly targets Linux-based OSes, but is effectively fully cross-platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What behavior most people expect from the --quiet option?

According to the [GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html), 4.7 Standards for Command Line Interfaces (and the [Options Table](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Option-Table)):

> ‘quiet’
>
> Used in many programs to inhibit the usual output. Every program accepting ‘--quiet’ should accept ‘--silent’ as a synonym.

So `--quiet` should suppress usual output, which is roughly things sent to `stdout`. `stderr` should probably be displayed since error messages concern unusual events.

---

> Errors?

Errors are exceptional or unusual events. I don't believe `--quiet` should affect them.

> User-valuable output? (e.g. grepped content for grep)

When a programs output is connected to another program's input, it is not uncommon for a program to change behavior. For example, some programs stop colorizing their output.

---

> Is there any documentation or reference out there that indicates the general consensus regarding command line interface behavior for Linux (Debian) tools?

[GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html) is one set of standards. Platforms like Red Hat or Debian may have additional guides. I've even seen guides from Free Desktop and Qt, but I am not sure if they cover the subject matter.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I will definitely have a look at the GNU coding standards